# What are the known issues for Magento versions?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, bug

Is there a public list (maintained by the community or by Magento) of all known issues for the different versions?
It seems like a no-brainer that such a list should exist, but at least I'm not aware of any.
Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: GooD Question @Vinai.........

Comment: I know for the enterprise version there is a patch list hidden somewhere deep in the Magento Admin which has all known issues and patches listed by version.

Comment: Still looking for an adequate answer on this. It would be such a beautiful thing. @Vinai - Amazon just informed me that Grokking Magento has shipped. I really can't wait :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yes but they're having some maintenance (same with discussion board) so I'm not sure if it's updated recently.*

---

Edit:
**It's working again, you can visit it by clicking through this link:**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/list 
This list can be sorted by Magento version where bug occured.

**If you want to report a new bug:**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the bug tracker contains many records that probably are related to third party modules (for example http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/311). Still, since there is no better answer available I'll accept yours :)

Answer (score 2):

[Release notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes) exists, but I don't think there is any (community) ran list for all the issues.